# Use own imports for imported project in Java

Tags: android, import, jaxb

after many hours of work, I got jaxb working with android.
I created many own jar-files with own prefixes (instead of javax.xml.bind.* I called it rebuild.javax.xml.bind.*).
It works fine for classes in my project, but I have to make it work for classes in an other imported (Java BuildPath ->Projects ) project, but every class of the imported project references to javax.xml. and so it crashes my app if I run it(because in android there is no javax.xml.bind).

I have no write-access to the other project, how can I make it work?
If I copy every class in the second project and  chage the imports von javax to rebuild.javax, it works fine, but I can't reimport it every time something changed.

Sry for my bad english, I hope you guys understand me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use a custom `ClassLoader` that replaces occurences of `javax.xml.bind.*` by `rebuild.javax.xml.bind.*` just before loading its classes.

Something like this :

```
public class JaxbClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    [...]

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if(name.startsWith("javax.xml.bind"))
            name = "rebuild." + name;
        super.loadClass(name);
    }
}
```

Maybe `Class.findClass` should be overridden too, but i'm not sure.
Then, you create a custom `Application` class and replace its `ClassLoader` like this :

```
private ClassLoader loader;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
    if(loader == null)
        loader = new JaxbClassLoader(super.getClassLoader());
    return loader;
}
```

Don't forget to declare your `Application` in the `AndroidManifest`.
Setting the context class loader is additional, but may be of use.
Overriding `getClassLoader()` will cause the returned loader to be used in `Activities` created inside this app context.

Under some specific conditions, you might have to explicitly set the CCL once again, for example, upon creation of new `Thread`. A `ThreadLocal` might be of help in this case.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and I think it will be the solution for my problem, but there are some more problems: I think I have to add an external jar, if I want to load it in runtime, otherwise I get a classnotfoundexception (because the class was not loaded at build, I think). But if I load the classes from the external jar, I get noclassdeffounderror.

Comment: I recently managed to do that as well by putting the jar in `assets`, then copying it in internal storage, and finally using a `DexClassLoader`. It was with an `apk` though, so maybe some minor modifications are necessary for `jar`.

Comment: Additionally : your `jar` cannot include classes that are already on your classpath. This would result in some classes being loaded twice, which is seen as a security issue by the VM and linking of classes importing such classes will fail, resulting indirectly in a `ClassNotFoundException` or `NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: It works if I load the class via loader.loadClass("rebuild.blablabla").newInstance(); But not automatically, I will create a new Thread for this.